# How to create an object of a STI subclass using ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Given the following setup(which is not working currently)

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Manager < Employee
end

ActiveAdmin.register Employee do
  form do |f|
    f.input :name
    f.input :joining_date
    f.input :salary
    f.input :type, as: select, collection: Employee.descendants.map(&:name)
  end
end
```

I would like to have a single "new" form for all employees and be able to select the STI type of the employee in the form.
I am able to see the select box for "type" as intended but when I hit the "Create" button, I get the following error:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in Admin::EmployeesController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: type
```

Now, I am aware of the way protected attributes work in Rails and I have a couple of workarounds such as defining `Employee.attributes_protected_by_default` but that is lowering the security and too hack-y.

I want to be able to do this using some feature in ActiveAdmin but I can't find one. I do not want to have to create a custom controller action as the example I showed is highly simplified and contrived.

I wish that somehow the controller generated by ActiveAdmin would identify `type` and do `Manager.create` instead of `Employee.create`

Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 10):

You can customize the controller yourself. Read [ActiveAdmin Doc on Customizing Controllers](http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#modify_the_controller). Here is a quick example:

```ruby
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  controller do
    alias_method :create_user, :create

    def create
      # do what you need to here
      # then call create_user alias
      # which calls the original create
      create_user
      # or do the create yourself and don't
      # call create_user
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Newer versions of the `inherited_resources` gem have a [BaseHelpers](https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources/blob/master/lib/inherited_resources/base_helpers.rb) module. You can override its methods to change how the model is altered, while still maintaining all of the surrounding controller code. It's a little cleaner than `alias_method`, and they have hooks for all the standard REST actions:

```
controller do
  # overrides InheritedResources::BaseHelpers#create_resource
  def create_resource(object)
    object.do_some_cool_stuff_and_save
  end

  # overrides InheritedResources::BaseHelpers#destroy_resource
  def destroy_resource(object)
    object.soft_delete
  end
end
```