# custom destroy/edit functions in rails active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, inherited-resources

I'd like to add some custom code to the destroy and edit default actions in active admin. Essentially, when I edit or delete a member, I want to sync that action with a copy on an external database.

I could either do a redirect to a custom method to do that then redirect back to the index, or create my own action in place of the default actions I could call.

Is there a better way to do this? preferably by just modifying the active admin destroy and edit functions?

Comment: i think callbacks are a got fit in this case, `after_update` and `after_destroy`

Answer (score 4):

[Customize controller answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11818159/349423)

The example overrides create, but you can do the same with `update` and `destroy`.